# setState is not helping in rebuilding widget tree

Tags: flutter

```
    class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Card(
              color: Colors.pink[50],
              elevation: 80,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [Text("Total Income:$b"), Text("Total Expenses: $a")],
              )),
          FinalList(),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

I have this code, I have a statefull widget FinalList implemented in some other file. When the list is updated I want to change its display as well. But I am unable to achieve this. I tried making a function and calling set state but it returned nothing. Then I removed the set state and simply tried to return FinalList and it brought no change. I have to go back and then reload the page to get updated list.

Answer (score 0):

make your class _BodyState like BodyState.

after changing the class name you shoud initialize that class in file which is returning finallist like this.

```html
BodtState state = BodtState();
```

and when you are return new final list just write

```html
state.setState(() {
      
    });
```

it will work.

Comment: ```Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
   
      child: new ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: titles.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Card(
              child: new Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),

Comment: child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(titles[index]),
                      Text(prices[index].toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }``` My finalList file is follows.

Comment: Where should I put this. state.setState(() {
      
    });